# How can we add multiple subscriptions to one On-Premise Data Gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, powerbi-datagateway

We would like to connect our Azure Analysis Services to a Managed Instance.
There are 3 different subscriptions, Develop, Pre-Prod and Production

The public endpoints on the Managed Instances are turned off. So we are using an On-Premise Data Gateway on two local servers (in a cluster). 
We connected this Gateway in the Production subscription, however the Gateway can only be connected to one subscription. So it would seem.

The following links suggests that it should be working.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90f97925-60e3-43de-8a98-b565ee8fe4dd/onpremise-gateway-across-multiple-subscriptions?forum=azurelogicapps

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20569843-on-premise-data-gateway-support-for-multiple-subsc

What could we be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share your gateway across multiple subscriptions, you just need to have the "contributor" role on the Gateway Connection in Azure.
Then in the Logic App, if for example you want to use the FILE connector, you have to create a connection to the file system, when you are in the connection screen, you just need to select the Subscription where your gateway is, and then select the gateway. As simple as that.
The only thing you can't do is use a gateway from a subscription that is not in the same tenant as the subscription where you want to use it.